# Ionic 4 PWA and native android/ios service worker caching

Tags: ionic-framework, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

I am working on an **Ionic 4/capacitor** app which will be released as PWA, iOs and android native app. I am using **angular service worker caching** mechanism(using ngsw-config.json file) to cache some responses. It works fine on browser. Both writing to and fetching from cache works seamlessly without writing any piece of code. 
My confusion is, will this service worker caching works on native android/iOs ionic 4 apps?

If not, then i would have to write caching functions( both get() and set()) in my code to cache responses/images(using **ionic storage** etc) . But then if my service worker caching is on and these caching methods are also in my code , wouldn't there be **duplicate cache writes** for the same stuff ?

I am not sure how to handle this because i am new to Ionic4/PWA world. Please suggest a caching architectural design which works in all three modes i.e. PWA, iOS and android.

Appreciate and thanks in advance.